# How do I format decimal point in cells, dependent on value of characters? [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large column of data in a Google Sheet, which contains data size values for KB, MB and GB. The problem is I need to calculate the total size of data we have, but the column has these different data values and so the decimal point within the value is placed differently, depending on it's data type.

Example being:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╗
║ Row ║   Size    ║
╠═════╬═══════════╣
║   1 ║ 43.48 MB  ║
║   2 ║ 150.69 KB ║
║   3 ║ 1.45 GB   ║
╚═════╩═══════════╝
```

Is there a way to make it so the following happens:

1. If "KB" appears in cell value, then remove KB and decimal point. Insert "0." at the beginning of value: 0.15069
2. If "MB" appears in cell value, then remove MB.
3. If "GB" appears in cell value, then remove GB and decimal point. Add "0" at the end of value: 1450

Relatively new to Google Sheets, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, e.g. using nested `IF()` formulas. I find in those cases the `SWITCH` is a good one to use ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=en&authuser=0)):

`=SWITCH(right(A1,2),"GB",left(A1,len(A1)-3)*10,"MB",left(A1,Len(A1)-3)*1,"KB",left(A1,len(A1)-3)*1/100,"we're in Terabyte country now (or missing data)")`

Detail:

- Use `RIGHT` and `LEFT` to extract from the string in the data.
- Use `LEN` to extract everything except the suffix.
- Multiply *values* by 1 to convert string to value.

Comment: Hey, I changed the "(A1)-3)*10" and "(A1)-3)*1/100" so they are: "(A1)-3)*1000" and"(A1)-3)*1/1000".

It did exactly what I needed it to do! Thank you so much for the formula and providing a break down of why you used what you used!